# Generalising the resolution of identity

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:** Let $V$ be a separable Hilbert space over $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with an inner product $\left(,\right)$. Let $B=\left\{ b_{i}\right\} _{i\in I}$ for some countable (possibly finite) index set $I$ be an orthonormal basis of $V$. Let $a,a'$  be some vectors of $V$. We know the basic result

$$\sum_{i\in I}\left(a,b_{i}\right)\left(a',b_{i}\right)=\left(a,a'\right).$$

following from the resolution of identity. Is there a generalisation of this to a larger set of vectors $A\subset V$, ie, can

$$\sum_{i\in I}\prod_{a\in A}\left(a,b_{i}\right)=\sum_{i\in I}\left(a_{1},b_{i}\right)\left(a_{2},b_{i}\right)\ldots$$

be expressed eg in terms of the inner products of the vectors of $A$? I'm expecially interested in the special case of $V=\mathbb{R}^{n}$, with $\left(,\right)$ being the basic “dot” product.

**Context:** Consider integrals of the form

$$\intop_{S^{n-1}}f\left(\left(x,u\right)\right)\mu\left(u\right),~x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}.$$

It's fairly simple to obtain a series representation for them (by choosing a spherical coordinate system so that the inner product is determined by a single angle $\left(x,u\right)\equiv\left|x\right|\cos\theta
$) at least assuming that $f$ can be expressed as an absolutely convergent power series $f\left(\left(x,u\right)\right)=\sum_{k}c_{k}\left|x\right|^{k}\cos^{k}\theta$. I tried to generalise this to cases where the integrand depends on several constant vectors $\left\{ x_k\right\} _{k=1}^{K}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n} , k\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,K\right\}$. A “natural” way of doing this (again, assuming that there is a power series representation of the integrand with sufficient convergence properties) seemed to be to write

$$\intop_{S^{n-1}}g\left(\left(x_{1},u\right),\left(x_{2},u\right)\ldots\left(x_{K},u\right)\right)\mu\left(u\right)=\sum_{n_{1}n_{2}\ldots n_{K}}C_{n_{1}n_{2}\ldots n_{K}}\intop_{S^{n-1}}\left(x_{1},u\right)^{n_{1}}\left(x_{2},u\right)^{n_{2}}\ldots\left(x_{K},u\right)^{n_{K}}\mu\left(u\right)$$

corresponding to the evaluation of integrals of the form

$$\intop_{S^{n-1}}\prod_{a\in A}\left(a,u\right)\mu\left(u\right)=\frac{1}{n}\intop_{S^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\prod_{a\in A}\left(a,H^{k}u\right)\mu\left(u\right),$$

where $\left\{ H^{k}u\right\} _{k=0}^{n-1}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for some fixed $H\in\mathrm{SO}\left(n\right)$. This felt like the natural direction for generalising because for $\left|A\right|=2$, it can be used with the "resolution of identity" identity to obtain $\intop_{S^{n-1}}\left(a,u\right)\left(a',u\right)\mu\left(u\right)=\frac{1}{n}\left(a,a'\right)$, with normalisation $\mu\left(S^{n-1}\right)=1$.

Hence my question – it seems like a generalisation of the identity could make calculating these integrals a lot easier (which is why I'm a bit skeptical about it being possible, it seems a bit “too easy”). I'd also be interested in other methods for evaluating such integrals, say in the special case of functions depending on only two or three dot products.

*Nb:* I have a physics background, so the notation might be nonstandard or there might be some other weirdness going on, sorry about that. In particular, I'm not sure if referring to the initial identity as a resolution of identity in the context of finite-dimensional vector spaces is correct, and consequently the title of my question might be a bit strange.